# How to correctly use Jasmine spies to mock transactions

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to mock the behaviour from my transaction module in my account_spec. I am finding it difficult. Once, I make a deposit from my account, I have to mock the behaviour for the transaction but I am finding it very hard. My test is currently returning `'Transaction' is not undefined`

EDIT:

I have an account module:

```
function Account(statement = new Statement, transaction = new Transaction){
  this._statement = statement
  this._transaction = transaction
}

Account.prototype.deposit = function(amount) {
  this._transaction.deposit(amount)
  this._statement.storeHistory(amount, this._balance, "Deposit")
}

Account.prototype.withdraw = function(amount) {
  this._transaction.withdraw(amount)
  this._statement.storeHistory(amount, this._balance, "Withdraw")
}

Account.prototype.balance = function() {
  return this._balance
}
module.exports = Account;
```

I have a transaction module:

```
function Transaction(){
    this._balance = 0
}

Transaction.prototype.balance = function() {
    return this.balance
}

Transaction.prototype.deposit = function(amount) {
    this._balance += amount
}

Transaction.prototype.withdraw = function(amount) {
    this._balance -= amount
}

module.exports = Transaction;
```

My Statement:

```
function Statement(){
  this._logs = []
}

Statement.prototype.seeStatement = function() {
  return this._logs
}

Statement.prototype.storeHistory = function(amount, balance, type) {
  this._logs.push({amount: amount, balance: balance, type: type})
}

module.exports = Statement;
```

My Account Spec:

```
'use strict';

describe('Account',function(){
  var account;
  beforeEach(function(){
    statement = new Statement
    var transactionSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('transaction',['balance','withdraw','deposit']);
    account = new Account(statement, transactionSpy);
  });
  it('is able for a user to deposit', function(){
    account.deposit(40)
    // expect(account.balance()).toEqual(40)
  });
  it('is able for a user to withdraw', function() {
    account.deposit(40)
    account.withdraw(20)
    // expect(account.balance()).toEqual(20)
  });
  it('is able for a user to check their balance', function() {
    account.deposit(20)
    expect(transaction.balance()).toEqual(20)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code written by [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6528560/alexander-poshtaruk) is correct except one note. You need to pass spy to Account constructor. The name `transaction` you pass to `jasmine.createSpyObj` is just a name that will be used in error messages. you can omit it (in this case it will be `unknown`)

```js
beforeEach(function() {
    var transactionSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('transaction',['returnBalance','withdraw','deposit']);
    account = new Account(transactionSpy, statement)
  });
```

Comment: I have added what you have shown. However, it keeps on saying back to me 'transaction is not defined'. Could you kindly take a look at my edited code above in my test?

Comment: I thought have I have defined it in my transactionSpy variable?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much.

Comment: 1st mistake - you had transactionSpy and statementSpy defined out of access in scope level
2nd mistake - I'm not sure that expect(transaction.balance()).toEqual(20) is the correct way of unit testing here. It looks like you want to have integration test. In this case you do not need spies

Answer (score 1):

Actually I see typo here, or maybe code is incomplete:

```
describe('Account', function() {
  var account;
  var transaction;
var statement = {}; //or some mock object

  beforeEach(function() {
    var spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('transaction',['returnBalance','withdraw','deposit']);
    account = new Account(transaction, statement)
  });

  it("is able to deposit money", function() {
    account.deposit(40)
    expect(transaction.returnBalance).toEqual(40)
    });
});
```